# Maximum product of 13 adjacent numbers

Tags: c#

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>();
long max = 0;
long mul = 1;
string abc = @"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
               85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
               96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
               12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
               66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
               62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
               30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
               70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
               65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
               52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
               53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
               83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
               82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
               16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
               17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
               24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
               07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
               84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
               05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
               71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

foreach (char a in abc)
{
    if(arr.Count == 13)
    {
        arr.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    int value = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(a);
    arr.Add(value);
    if(arr.Count == 13)
    {
        foreach(int b in arr)
        {
            mul = mul * b;
            if (mul > max)
            {
                max = mul;
            }
        }
        mul = 1;
    }
} 
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

I am getting 5377010688 which is a wrong answer and when I am trying same  logic with given example in project Euler it is working fine, please help me.

Don't say the answer just correct me where I am doing wrong or where the code is not running as it should.

Comment: You should not multiply 13 every time.  Multiply only the new and the n divide off the first (if it is not zero).  Name List arr is not good.  This breaks if it is max but then hits a zero before it gets to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't say the answer just correct me where I am doing wrong or where
>   the code is not running as it should

You have included all `characters` into calculation but you should not do that. The input `string` also contains for example carriage return `'\n'` at the end of each line.

Your actual string look like this:

```
string abc = @"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\r\n
               85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\r\n
...
```

How to solve this? You should ignore these characters, one possible solution is to check each `char` if it is a digit:

```
if(!char.IsDigit(a))
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: But is working fine when I have tried with the example given by project Euler and can you please elaborate i didn't understand

Comment: Try to print out `(int)Char.GetNumericValue('\n')`. You will see it is -1. In your `string` you have invisible characters at the end of each line `'\n'` which mess up your calculation. Of make your string to be in one line...

Comment: thanks for the answer,In that case it should not work for the example but it is working

Comment: And if you ask why Euler example works, probably because the final result is not somewhere at the transition between lines...

Answer (score 3):

The string constant, as it is written down like above, contains blanks and `\r\n`'s, e.g. between the last '4' of the first line and the first '8' on the second line. `Char.GetNumericValue()` returns -1 for a blank.
Propably the character sequence with the highest product spans across adjacent lines in your string, therefore there are blanks in between, which count as -1, which disables your code in finding them.

Write your constant like this:

`string abc = @"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
               "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
               "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +` etc.

The result is then 23514624000, I hope that's correct.

Comment: thanks it worked but why it was not a problem in example when I run same old code  ?

Comment: I mean without adding '+'

Comment: It didn't work, just a coincidence that expected result was somewhere in the middle not at the edges, try changing the input by adding 99 at the end of the line and at the beginning of the next line(and try 4 adjacent numers). Your original solution will return wrong answer...